# Covariance Matrices Help

Tags: matrices, regression, covariance

Consider two independent random variables $ξ_1$ and $ξ_2$, such that $ξ_1 ∼ N(0,1)$ and $ξ_2 ∼ N(0,2)$. Let $η_1 =(ξ_1+ξ_2, ξ_2)^{T}$,  $η_2 =(ξ_1, ξ_1−ξ_2)^{T}$. Find the covariance matrix between $η_1$ and $η_2$.

How would I go about answering this?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
cov(\eta_2, \eta_1) &= \mathbb{E} \eta_2^T \eta_1 - \mathbb{E}\eta_2\mathbb{E}\eta_1\\
                    &=\mathbb{E} \begin{bmatrix}\xi_1^2 + \xi_1\xi_2,&\xi_1\xi_2\\ \xi_1^2 - \xi_2^2,&\xi_1\xi_2-\xi_2^2 \end{bmatrix}\\
                    &=\begin{bmatrix}1,&0\\-1,&-2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}